# Browser problem with smartgwt drag & drop

Tags: smartgwt, drag-and-drop

I'm new to smartGWT. I've taken GWT components in a canvas that is draggable & added it into VStack. My code is working fine in IE but it is dissapearing on Firefox/Chrome. Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to freely intermix SmartGWT and GWT components, which is something we don't recommend doing.  See [this item](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aMix) in the SmartGWT FAQ.

Specific patterns of mixing GWT components into SmartGWT (and vice versa) are supported (the above FAQ item explains this).  If you think your usage falls into one of those patterns, post a standalone test case of what you're trying to do (to the SmartGWT Forums).